# JS-Data slow jasmine tests after inject

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, jsdata, js-data-angular

I am having a JS-Data resource in angularjs, and every time I call `inject` on it in a (Jasmine) test, the test slows down, taking up to 700ms.

I am already doing an `ejectAll()` after each test. It is not doing any `$http` requests either, so I am out of clues...

Any ideas why JS-Data injections might be so slow in my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: in my resource definition I set the `UseClass` property to a model that changed the instance, replacing an array with a getter through `Object.defineProperty`.
As stated [here](http://www.js-data.io/docs/events):

> The DS.change fires on a Resource whenever any item in the Store for
>   that Resource changes.

The getter resulted in JS-Data to think the instance changed, triggering an infinite digest loop. After 10 digests angular gives up, but it takes some time, leading to slow tests.

Lesson learned: don't extend persistend DS model instances with getter properties, as they trigger infinite changes.